# Django: get_object_or_404 does not return existing object

Tags: python, django, sqlite, resolve

I hope someone with more knowledge of Django could tell what might be going on, because I feel I have checked everything and can't make sense of it.

I have a simple view which works perfectly fine, where entries are retrieved based on the unique string in the url:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    # url(r'^bib/(?P<unique_str>\w+-\w+-\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+)$', 'nl.views.text_detail', name='text_detail'),
    # ...
    )


# views.py
import myapp.models
import django.shortcuts

def text_detail(request, unique_str, slug):
    entry= django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404(myapp.models.Entry, unique_str=unique_str)
    return django.shortcuts.render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'entry': entry,})
```

However, when I call the exact same function in another view with the exact same arguments, it raises `Http404`. (When I run the `Entry.objects.get(unique_str=unique_str)` method, it raises the model's `DoesNotExist` exception.)

That view is an AJAX view which is accessed with a simple URL and accepts posted JSON data containing a URL. Based on the URL that is passed, I want to retrieve the relevant Entry and do some processing for it.

Given an url that would display the text_detail view nicely in the browser, the view below fails on get_object_or_404():

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    # url(r'^sendurl/$', 'nl.views.sendurl', name='sendurl'),
    # ...
    )

# views.py
import json
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
import django.shortcuts
import myapp.models


def sendurl(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        data = json.loads(request.POST['jsonData'])
        url = data['url']

        resolvermatch = resolve(url)
        if resolvermatch.view_name == 'text_detail':
            unique_str = resolvermatch.kwargs['unique_str']
            slug = resolvermatch.kwargs['slug']

            # When I put these lines, it actually prints out the HTML of the text_detail view:
            # response = nl.views.text_detail(request, unique_str, slug)
            # print response

            # But this fails:
            entry = django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404(myapp.models.Entry, unique_str=unique_str)

            # Do Entry processing
            # entry.save()

        else ... :
            # ...

    else:
        raise Http404
```

How is this possible?

I am using Django 1.6 and SQLite database (in development).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Yep, that's the real app's name. I've edited it. I'm not having any `ImportError` though.

Comment: is the `unique_str`relevant? If you remove that, does the issue change at all? Alternatively, are you sure you're passing in the proper string?

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Do you use ipdb or something like that? May be last string "raise Http404" causes 404. Try to place there something like HttpResponse('request.is_ajax() is false')

Comment: The unique_str is not technically the primary key, but it is an indexed unique reference number (which makes more sense to humans). The proper string seems to be passed since I can `print response` after assigning it as `response = nl.views.text_detail(request, unique_str, slug)`. (This also shows that I am in the `is_ajax()` block.)

Comment: UPDATE: I decided to test this with the production database (PostgreSQL) and there it worked fine..